# How to fix this capitalization issue of a macro in the title-command?

Tags: macros, formatting, titles, capitalization

I wrote the following code to typeset the title page of a paper:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title[Title Title Title]{Title Title Title}

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

This outputs the following:

[image]

However, I wanted to make my title a macro, because I need it elsewhere too:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\newcommand\mytitle{Title title title}

\begin{document}

\title[\mytitle]{\mytitle}

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

But this now outputs the following:

[image]

No way of fiddling got me the capitalization back. E.g. there is no difference in using `\def`. What is happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: `\expandafter\title\expandafter{\mytitle} ` should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried this, and unformtunately it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `amsart` uses by default `\uppercase` (a big nuisance). Happily, the fix is simple: load `textcase`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{textcase}

\newcommand\mytitle{Title title title}

\begin{document}

\title[\mytitle]{\mytitle}

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's see the definition of `\title`

```
\renewcommand*{\title}[2][]{\gdef\shorttitle{#1}\gdef\@title{#2}}
\edef\title{\@nx\@dblarg
  \@xp\@nx\csname\string\title\endcsname}
```

This is a common trick in the class for telling LaTeX that if the optional argument is missing then the mandatory argument should be supplied instead.

The problem arises when `\maketitle` is processed, which does `\@settitle`:

```
\def\@settitle{\begin{center}%
  \baselineskip14\p@\relax
    \bfseries
\uppercasenonmath\@title
  \@title
  \end{center}%
}
```

OK, we should look at `\uppercasenonmath`:

```
\newcommand{\uppercasenonmath}[1]{\toks@\@emptytoks
  \@xp\@skipmath\@xp\@empty#1$$%
  \edef#1{{\@nx\protect\@nx\@upprep\the\toks@}}%
}
```

This only expands `\@title` once, so at the end the primitive `\uppercase` is applied to `\mytitle` (it would be a bit long to go into the details). However the class also has

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifundefined{MakeTextUppercase}{}{\let\uppercasenonmath\altucnm}%
}
```

and we find

```
\def\altucnm#1{%
  \MakeTextUppercase{\toks@{#1}}%
  \edef#1{\the\toks@}%
}
```

and this is much better, because `\MakeTextUppercase` does full (protected) expansion of its argument, so your `\mytitle` gets expanded *before* uppercasing is done.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. Can you tell a little bit about why this problem happened in the first place and how textcase fixed it?

Comment: @M.Winter Added some details

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\title\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter[\expandafter\mytitle\expandafter]\expandafter{\mytitle}
```

But @egreg answer is worthwile reading too. :)

Comment: Wow, this is insanity. I mean I tried `\expandafter`, but I was not aware that just using *more* might fix the problem :D

Comment: eh eh... you usually need them by groups of `2^n -1` here `n=2` because we need to expand once two things.

Comment: `\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}} ... \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\mytitle}{\expandafter\title\expandafter[\mytitle]}`

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes, and with `\unexpanded\expandafter{\foo}` methods it is even easier to control expansion in arbitrary locations in an `\edef`, `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\title[\unexpanded\expandafter{\mytitle}]{\unexpanded\expandafter{\mytitle}}}\x`