# How does one make just one word in the title a different color?

Tags: color, titles, amsart

The following works to give the title all in black:

```
\title{The Title}
```

But this does not work to make the first word in the title red:

```
\title{{\color{red}The} Title}
```

How does one make just one word in the title a different color?

Comment: `\textcolor{red}{The}` should work in a standard class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not work either. Could the problem be my use of \documentclass ?

Comment: Well, you should post a minimal non-working example code.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful advice. Here is a minimal non-working example code: \documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{color}
\title{The title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\title` under [`amsart`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsart) is set in CAPITAL LETTERS. As such, merely using

```
\title{\textcolor{red}{The} title}
```

doesn't work out-of-the-box because there is no colour `RED`. However, it's simple enough to define `RED` to be the same as `red`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{RED}{red}
\title{\textcolor{red}{The} title}
\author{An Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With `amsart` there is the problem of capitalization, but it is easily solved.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcase}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\title[The title]{\foo{The} title}
\author{An Author}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Use a more meaningful name than `\foo`, of course. Omit the optional argument if you also want the coloring in the page headings.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468247/4427 for details about why loading `textcase` is better for the application.

The rationale for defining a command is that hardwiring a color means having to chase for every occurrence in the document for it, whereas with a command you can just modify the definition in case you change your mind about what color to use (or no color at all).